# I want to add a counter in a sequence 1-9 if a cell contains any text

Tags: google-sheets

I am feeding a spreadsheet from Zapier so when a action happends a row is added to the bottom. I want to use an arrayformula that adds a counter to the new row that has been added. I want it to count from 1-9 and then restart. So my plan was to use a formula similar to this.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISTEXT(A3:A),(IF(J3:J>9,J3:J+1,1)))
```

And I would have a manual entered 1 in J2. This doesn't work. But you might see what im thinking?

Please assist me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i managed to solve this. But it might not be the cleanest solution. Please come with suggestions if you have any.

This code works

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),(ROW(A2:A)-ROUNDDOWN(ROW(A2:A),-1)),""))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Enter this formula in K2:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A)+J2:J>9,1,0))`

And this formula into L2:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(K2:K=0,"",SUMIF(ROW(K2:K),"<="&ROW(A2:A),K2:K)))`

The result:

[image]

---

**References**

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/37799/cumulative-sum-without-script

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. I like how you solved it. But the problem for me is that i want the counter to restart when it reaches 9. So insterad if 10 it should start with 1 again. And it actually only have to look to if there is text in column a. and then return the number in J. So i did some minor changes to your formula. In K i put =ArrayFormula(IF(ISTEXT(A2:A),1,""))  And in J i put: '=ArrayFormula(IF(K2:K="","",SUMIF(ROW(K2:K),"<="&ROW(A2:A),K2:K)))'